# In Python, how do I take a string of averages and sort them?

Tags: python

`player_avg` is a string that contains batting averages for baseball players separated by commas:

```
player_avg = "0.209,0.305,0.265,0.175,0.324,0.215,0.362,0.178,0.273,0.309"
```

How do I write code to compute the number of players that batted greater than 0.299, and store the result in the variable `num_players_over_300` ?

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote that produced the wrong output?

Comment: Which are you asking to do, sort the numbers, or find the ones over a certain value?

Comment: So 0.300 counts as "over" 300?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you actually tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into a list, then sort it. Get only the values over 0.300.

```
avg_list = sorted([float(avg) for avg in player_avg.split(',')])
players_over_300 = [avg for avg in avg_list if avg > 0.3]
num_players_over_300 = len(players_over_300)
```

Comment: why would you need to sort before ?

Comment: His title is "In Python, how do I take a string of averages and sort them?".

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative with list comprehension:

```
player_avg = "0.209,0.305,0.265,0.175,0.324,0.215,0.362,0.178,0.273,0.309"
num_players_over_300 = len([float(i) for i in player_avg.split(',') if float(i) > 0.299])
```

Output:
4

Answer (score 0):

1. This is your code

   ---

   ```
   l= "0.209,0.305,0.265,0.175,0.324,0.215,0.362,0.178,0.273,0.309"
   numberList = list(map(float,l.split(",")))
   num_of_players=0

   for i in numberList:
       if i>0.299:
           num_of_players+=1
   print(num_of_players)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Code with basic steps that you can learn -

```
>>> player_avg = "0.209,0.305,0.265,0.175,0.324,0.215,0.362,0.178,0.273,0.309"
>>> player_avg.split(',')
['0.209', '0.305', '0.265', '0.175', '0.324', '0.215', '0.362', '0.178', '0.273', '0.309']
>>> arr = player_avg.split(',')
>>> arr
['0.209', '0.305', '0.265', '0.175', '0.324', '0.215', '0.362', '0.178', '0.273', '0.309']
>>> op = []
>>> for i in arr:
...  if float(i) > 0.299:
...   op.append(float(i))
...
>>> op
[0.305, 0.324, 0.362, 0.309]
>>> op.sort()
>>> op
[0.305, 0.309, 0.324, 0.362]
>>>
```